# Call another installed package in Python

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to Python. What I want to do is after setup [esptool](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) package (`pip install esptool`) call its main method with a bunch of arguments in my application. Something like:

```
esptool.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash -fm qio 0x0000
```

There is an issue I faced. `esptool` is not on the packages list in python to import (it is installed with pip already). How am I gonna user `import` and call the main method?

Comment: OS? Python version?

Comment: How do you get the packages list? Do you import with the same Python version as used for `pip`? Compare `python --version` and `pip --version`.

Comment: What about just using subprocess? That's what you're showing here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resolving import issues

You can't simply invoke `import esptool` because `esptool.py` is an executable script, thus not meant to be imported like a plain module. However, there are workarounds for importing code from executable scripts; here are two I know of:

### extending `sys.path`

You can extend the `sys.path` to include the bindir containing the `esptool.py` script. Simple check from command line:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=$(which esptool.py)/.. python -c "import esptool; esptool.main()"
```

should print you the usage help text.

Extending `sys.path` in code:

```
import os
import sys

try:
    from shutil import which
except ImportError:
    from distutils.spawn import find_executable as which


bindir = os.path.dirname(which('esptool.py'))
sys.path.append(bindir)  # after this line, esptool becomes importable

import esptool


if __name__ == '__main__':
    esptool.main()
```

### using import machinery

You can avoid extending `sys.path` by using the mechanisms of importing Python code from arbitrary files. I like this solution more than fiddling with `sys.path`, but unfortunately, it is not portable between Python 2 and 3.

#### Python 3.5+

```
import importlib.machinery
import importlib.util

from shutil import which


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('esptool', which('esptool.py'))
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
    esptool = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    loader.exec_module(esptool)  # after this line, esptool is imported

    esptool.main()
```

#### Python 2.7

```
import imp
from distutils.spawn import find_executable as which


if __name__ == '__main__':
    esptool = imp.load_source('esptool', which('esptool.py'))
    esptool.main()
```

## Passing command line arguments

The command line arguments are stored in `sys.argv` list, so you will have to temporarily overwrite it in order to pass the arguments to the main function:

```
# assuming esptool is imported
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # save the current arguments
    argv_original = sys.argv[:]
    # overwrite arguments to be passed to esptool argparser
    sys.argv[:] = ['', '-p', '/dev/ttyUSB0', 'write_flash', '-fm', 'qio', '0x0000']
    try:
        esptool.main()
    except Exception:
        # TODO deal with errors here
        pass
    finally:  # restore original arguments
        sys.argv[:] = argv_original
```

Comment: "You can't simply invoke import esptool because...". Your reasoning seems flawed here. Your conclusions are fine though. As you show, the only reason you can't import it is it's not in the path.

Comment: Ah, this is what you mean - indeed, in this case the only problem is the path. My intention was to underline that I don't consider it to be a good practice in general due to other issues that may emerge, for example scripts having names that are not valid module name identifiers, or script missing a main block etc.